# terraform Error: Invalid for_each argument error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to check if Azure Private dns zone Private link is already created or not.If not create i will create resource.I am running az clin commands , dumping all private link and comparing if it exists or not. But when i try to run below code getting this error.same error for count .Any idea how to resolve this error ?

```
Error: Invalid for_each argument
│
│   on main.tf line 118, in resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "pvdnsvnl":
│  118:   for_each = data.local_file.foo.content == "Privatelink_doesnotexist"  ? [] : [1]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.local_file.foo.content is a string, known only after apply
│
│ The "for_each" map includes keys derived from resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform
│ cannot determine the full set of keys that will identify the instances of this resource.
│
│ When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to define the map keys statically in your configuration and
│ place apply-time results only in the map values.
│
│ Alternatively, you could use the -target planning option to first apply only the resources that the for_each value
│ depends on, and then apply a second time to fully converge.
```

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "postgres-rg" {
  name = var.resourcegrp
}

resource "time_rotating" "postgres_admin_passwordchangedays" {
  rotation_days = var.password_changedays
}

resource "random_password" "postgresadminpassword" {
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "_%@"
  keepers = {
    expiry = time_rotating.postgres_admin_passwordchangedays.rotation_rfc3339
  }
}


#Create a postgres Flexible Server
resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "postgres-flexible-server" {
  name                   = var.postgres_servername
  resource_group_name    = var.resourcegrp
  location               = var.location
  version                = var.postgres_version
  administrator_login    = var.postgres_admin_login
  administrator_password = random_password.postgresadminpassword.result
  storage_mb             = var.postgres_storage
  sku_name               = var.postgres_sku_name
  delegated_subnet_id    = data.azurerm_subnet.postgresvnetsubnet.id
  private_dns_zone_id    = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.pv.id
 # depends_on             = [azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.pvdnsvnl]
  zone = var.primary_availability_zone
  dynamic "high_availability" {
    for_each = var.ha_enable == "yes" ? [1] : []
    content {
      mode                      = "ZoneRedundant"
      standby_availability_zone = var.standby_availability_zone
    }
  }
  backup_retention_days        = var.backup_retentiondays
  geo_redundant_backup_enabled = var.georedundantbackupenabled
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [tags, zone, high_availability.0.standby_availability_zone]
  }
  maintenance_window {
    day_of_week = var.maintenance_window_schedule_utc[0]
    start_hour  = var.maintenance_window_schedule_utc[1]
  }
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "postgresvnet" {
  name                = var.vnetnetworkname
  resource_group_name = var.vnetresourcegrp
  provider            = azurerm.vnetsubscription
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "postgresvnetsubnet" {
  name                 = var.vnetsubnetname
  virtual_network_name = var.vnetnetworkname
  resource_group_name  = var.vnetresourcegrp
  provider             = azurerm.vnetsubscription
}

data "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "pv" {
  name                = "privatelink.postgres.database.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = "shared_private_dns_zones_rg"
  provider            = azurerm.cloudops
}

output "private_dns_zone_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.pv.max_number_of_virtual_network_links
}


resource "null_resource" "az_login" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az login --service-principal -u $ARM_CLIENT_ID -p $ARM_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $ARM_TENANT_ID"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "azvnetlinklist" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  depends_on = [null_resource.az_login, azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.postgres-flexible-server]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az network private-dns link vnet list  -g shared_private_dns_zone -z  privatelink.postgres.database.azure.com | grep -i name |  awk -F':' '{ print $2 }' | tr -d ' ' | awk -F',' '{ print $1 }'  > ${path.module}/azvnetlinklist.txt"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "finalvnetresult" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  depends_on = [null_resource.az_login, null_resource.azvnetlinklist, azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.postgres-flexible-server]
  provisioner "local-exec" {

    command = "/bin/bash ${path.module}/vnet.sh demo-privatelink.postgres.database.azure.com"
  }
}

data "local_file" "foo" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.az_login, null_resource.azvnetlinklist, null_resource.finalvnetresult, azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.postgres-flexible-server]
  filename   = "${path.module}/final.txt"
}

output "readfile" {
  value = data.local_file.foo.content
}



resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "pvdnsvnl" {
 # count                 = data.local_file.foo.content == "Privatelink_doesnotexist" ? 1 : 0
  for_each = data.local_file.foo.content == "Privatelink_doesnotexist"  ? [] : [1]
  name                  = "${var.vnetnetworkname}-privatelink.postgres.database.azure.com"
  private_dns_zone_name = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.pv.name
  virtual_network_id    = data.azurerm_virtual_network.postgresvnet.id
  resource_group_name   = "shared_private_dns_zones_rg"
  depends_on            = [data.local_file.foo]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear. Your `for_each` execution must be known at **planning** time. Also TF is not designed to "to check if Azure Private dns zone Private link is already created or not". Checking for existence of resource is simply functionality which TF does not support and probably will never support.

As the error says, you have to either use `-target` or make `for_each` depend on only static values.

Comment: Great answer as always. The only thing worth pointing out is that terraform is designed to check for status of existing resources... just only for those managed by the state. So one either uses a data source, requiring it to exist, or a resource, creating it. I'm not correcting you, @Marcin; I know you know this, but I write it for posterity.

Comment: @theherk Thanks for extra info supplementing the answer.